# Oracle Trigger: conditional insert or update

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create a trigger which it is responsible for inserting/updating data into table `x` when data is inserted to table `y`.

table `y` has the field `code` and if a record with the same `code` already exists in the table `x` then the trigger should update the record else it should insert a new records into table `x`.

I am new to oracle and know how to create a trigger for insertion or update. But, I do not know how create one to both insert and update based on the aforementioned condition.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

To shed more light on the issue:

Table `y` can have multiple records with the same `code` while table `x` can only have one record for each `code`(to keep only the latest status).

So, When a new record is inserted to table `y` I should decide whether I am going to insert the records on the table `x` or I am just gonna update the row which contains the `code`.

Comment: smells like `MERGE` what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a compound trigger to collate all the inserts and updates and then issue a single `MERGE` statement (rather than doing one `MERGE` for each changed row).

For example, if you have table `Y` that can contain data for multiple dates:

```sql
CREATE TABLE y (
  code INT,
  col1 INT,
  col2 INT,
  dt   DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY ( code, dt )
);
```

And table `X` that should contain the data for the latest date:

```sql
CREATE TABLE x (
  code INT PRIMARY KEY,
  col1 INT,
  col2 INT,
  dt   DATE
);
```

And want to keep `X` updated (but don't want to create it as a `VIEW` or `MATERIALIZED VIEW` and aren't going to `UPDATE` the `DT` column in table `Y`) then you could use the compound trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER log_y_changes_to_x
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON y
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  y_data y_table := y_table();
AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    y_data.EXTEND(1);
    y_data(y_data.COUNT) := y_object( :NEW.code, :NEW.col1, :NEW.col2, :NEW.dt );
  END AFTER EACH ROW;
AFTER STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO x
    USING (
      SELECT code,
             col1,
             col2,
             dt
      FROM   (
        SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY code ORDER BY dt DESC ) rn
        FROM   TABLE(y_data) t
      )
      WHERE rn = 1
    ) y
    ON ( y.code = x.code )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
      SET   col1 = y.col1,
            col2 = y.col2,
            dt   = y.dt
      WHERE y.dt >= x.dt
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT ( code, col1, col2, dt )
      VALUES ( y.code, y.col1, y.col2, y.dt );
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

And have the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE y_object IS OBJECT (
  code INT,
  col1 INT,
  col2 INT,
  dt   DATE
);

CREATE TYPE y_table IS TABLE OF y_object;
```

And you insert data:

```sql
INSERT INTO y ( code, col1, col2, dt )
SELECT 1, 0, 2, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 0, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 0, 3, DATE '2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Then table `X` contains:

> ```
> CODE | COL1 | COL2 | DT                 
> ---: | ---: | ---: | :------------------
>    2 |    0 |    3 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00
>    3 |    3 |    3 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00
>    1 |    0 |    2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00
> ```

And, if you update data:

```sql
UPDATE y
SET    col1 = col1 + 3
WHERE  code <= 2
AND    dt = DATE '2020-01-01';
```

Then table `X` contains *(note: the code `2` row was not updated as it was not the latest row):

> ```
> CODE | COL1 | COL2 | DT                 
> ---: | ---: | ---: | :------------------
>    2 |    0 |    3 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00
>    3 |    3 |    3 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00
>    1 |    3 |    2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00
> ```

And:

```sql
INSERT INTO y ( code, col1, col2, dt )
SELECT 3, 5, 5, DATE '2020-01-05' FROM DUAL;
```

Then `X` contains

> ```
> CODE | COL1 | COL2 | DT                 
> ---: | ---: | ---: | :------------------
>    2 |    0 |    3 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00
>    3 |    5 |    5 | 2020-01-05 00:00:00
>    1 |    3 |    2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00
> ```

And:

```sql
INSERT INTO y ( code, col1, col2, dt )
SELECT 3, 4, 4, DATE '2020-01-04' FROM DUAL;
```

Then `X` is unchanged as the row is older than the previous.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fdc6f11f08a7fad3c398ad8f07629dd1)*

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, I am not going to merge updates from one table to another and that is not exactly what I need. I am gonna change your code to see if it works. If you are interested what is my exact problem, I updated my question to give it clarity.

Comment: @MortezaBandi Updated. However, you would be better to edit your question with a [MRE] that gives a concrete problem rather than letting us some up with a solution that we think fits your problem only for you to say that it's not what you are after.